# Finding nth Partial Sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can someone tell me how I could find a formula for the nth partial sum of the series by using it to find the series' sum if the series converges?

[image]

Based on the following definition:

[image]

I would need to know how I could define `a` and `r`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$r$th term $=\frac1{(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{(r+2)-(r+1)}{(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac1{r+1}-\frac1{r+2}$

So, the given series is [Telescopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: [Edit] - Thanks for the additional info..

Comment: @Sebastian, welcome. Also find http://140.177.205.23/TelescopingSeries.html